# How to create an Android PopupWindow which will popup on top of whatever is currently active?

Tags: android, android-popupwindow

I want to create a popupWindow which behaves like a dialog. I will have a daemon running in the background and once the daemon receives a signal the popupWindow shall appear on top of whatever is currently happening on the screen.
The problem I've is that a dont know how to tell the popupWindow to appear on top of everything.

```
        LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view = li.inflate(R.layout.popup, null);
        final PopupWindow popup = new PopupWindow(view, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        Button btn = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.popup_cancel);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                popup.dismiss();
            }
        });
        popup.showAtLocation(findViewById(R.id.main), Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
```

With the above code i managed to get the popup to show and dismiss on it's cancel Button, but it only happens on top of the activity. How do can i tell the popupWindow to appear on top of everything?

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can create activity and use dialog theme include your desired layout in it then call it from a service

Comment: Sorry, i dont quite understand. Can you give some code maybe?

Comment: @vMysterion 
create activity , then in its layout put your dialog design 
then create a service as said here
https://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/create-service#java
then create intent to your new activity and start it from the service